# Swift/SwiftUI - Remove space above keyboard

Tags: swift, swiftui

Can you please let me know how I can remove the space above the keyboard in the picture below. I have confirmed that the space is related to the keyboard, and is only present when the keyboard is visible.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because of your constraints. When the keyboard pops up it may alter the frame view causing that issue. You may want to take a look at this stack overflow thread. [iPhone X keyboard appear showing extra space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286239/iphone-x-keyboard-appear-showing-extra-space)